# Inject an IHttpClientFactory inside a singleton service of an asp.net core web app to create some inner HttpClients that will never be disposed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ihttpclientfactory

is this the correct way to inject one or more `HttpClient` objects inside a singleton service with a constructor having many other arguments?

That is: invoking `builder.Services.AddHttpClient()`, recovering the `IHttpClientFactory` by `provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()` and injecting it inside the singleton object MyService?
In the real world `ASP.NET CORE 6` web app, `IHttpClientFactory` will be used to create several instances of `HttpClients` stright in the constructor of MyService. All the instances of `HttpClient` will be assigned to some inner fields inside some other inner classes of MyService class.
MyService object will be injected in the `Contollers` and the inner _httpClient field, togheter with the other `HttpClient` objects created by the `HttpClientFactory.CreateClient()` method inside MyService, will be used for sending all the http requests of the app without disposing the HttpClients.
Is that correct?
P.S. I tried to search some matching post but I didn't find anything.

```
    // Inside Program.cs
 
    builder.Services.AddHttpClient();   

    builder.Services.AddSingleton((IServiceProvider provider) =>
    {
        var httpClientFactory = provider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
        return new MyService(httpClientFactory, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);
    });

    // class MyService
            
     public class MyService
     {
        protected readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        protected readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

        public MyService(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, Class1 arg1, Class2 arg2, Class3 arg3, Class4 arg4)
        {
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
            // Create a new instance of HttpClient inside my singleton service.
            // will _httpClient be kept inside the singleton service as unique instance, during the entire life time cicle of the asp.net core web api?
            // Could be this approach correct?
            _httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            
            // Use _httpClient during the whole life time of the web app.
            ...
        }
     }
```

Comment: When you use `IHttpClientFactory` the lifetime of `HttpClient` instances doesn't matter anymore because they're just thin wrappers over the `HttpClientHandler` objects which are pooled and managed by the factory, so don't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks, I was suspecting it was like that, but I was not sure.

Comment: Creating long lived clients via the factory goes directly against the advice of Microsoft. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory#httpclient-lifetime-management

Comment: Use this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-8.0